# Quick way to test that all symbols are defined for a module, without full unittest coverage

Tags: python, symbols

Let's say I have the following test script:

```
def b(): return 1

def a():
    b()
    c()
```

This module has a bug: `c()` is not defined/imported. But running this script will not fail, because `a()` is not called, and thus `c()` is not really needed. But as soon as `a()` is called, for example from another module, or whenever I modify the script to call `a()`, it will fail.

In this very simple case, it is easy to cover all possible execution paths with a unittest, which is the advisable thing to do. Unfortunately, my code is quite complex and I have no material time to prepare unit tests to cover all possible execution paths (which is a problem in itself, and I hope to solve in the future, but is currently out of the question)

Is there any way of checking that all symbols in all execution paths are defined for a specific module, without actually testing all execution paths?

Answer (score 3):

A linter like [pylint](http://www.pylint.org/) or [pyflakes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes) will detect this sort of thing, via static analysis of the code.

They're very far from perfect though, as it is not possible in a dynamic language like Python to cover every possible path - without, as you say, actually running those paths. In my experience though they do catch a good number of errors.

Comment: Great, thanks. I have no experience with those, but I'll try anyway. I hope they are easy enough to use, at least to get basic reports.